# Multiple prompt questions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple program where there is a confirm window asking whether or not you want to play a game. If you click on yes, you are required to enter your name and age. There are some validations for these questions that if a user inputs an empty string, it loops back to the same question until the validation condition is met.

But the program just closes after the age is inputted.

My goal is to have that confirm pop again asking the user if they want to play the game (again).

How do I achieve that?

```js
var play = confirm('Do you want to play?');
 
 while(play){
  var name = prompt('Please enter your name');
  
  if(name == ''){
   alert('Please Enter a valid name')
  }else{
   alert("The name is " + name);
   break;
  }
 }
 
 while(play){
  var age = prompt('Please enter your age');
  
  if(age == ''){
   alert('Please enter valid age');
  }else{
   alert('Age is ' + age);
  }
 }
```

Comment: The while loops inside should not be using play.... play does not change inside the loop, name and age do....

Comment: Testing just for an empty string isn't enough, because if the user clicks the cancel button `prompt()` returns `null` rather than `''`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use another while loop here and add `play = confirm('Do you want to play?')` as condition of the loop. Also note that the loop for age in your code is infinite so you will need to use break there.

```js
var play;
while(play = confirm('Do you want to play?')){

while(play){
    var name = prompt('Please enter your name');

    if(name == ''){
        alert('Please Enter a valid name')
    }else{
        alert("The name is " + name);
        break;
    }
}

while(play){
    var age = prompt('Please enter your age');

    if(age == ''){
        alert('Please enter valid age');
    }else{
        alert('Age is ' + age);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So great! Thank you so much for the assistance!!